# Assigning values to C pointers using malloc without variable initialization

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665793/directly-assigning-values-to-c-pointers), I understand why the code below may not work:

```
int *ptr;
*ptr = 1000;
printf("%d", *ptr);
```

when I compiled and run it using: `gcc file.c; ./a.out` I got:

> Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./a.out

ptr here may point to a random location without an initialized variable. Is that correct?

However, when using `malloc()` that issue does not occur.

```
int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
*ptr = 1000;
printf("%d", *ptr);
```

Does malloc initialize the variable that its pointer is pointing to?

Comment: malloc() doesn't initialize the variable, but it reserves some space (size that you require) in memory, usually you require the the space needed by the size of the variable based on its type.

Comment: Is that a typo? `int *ptr = 1000;` Should that be `*ptr = 1000;` as in first code?

Comment: What do you mean with "withour variable initialization"? Assigning a value during definition of a variable is exactly an initialization. It does not matther where you get that value.

Comment: I was wondering why `int *ptr; *ptr = 1000` returns segmentation fault upon printing. When I used malloc, this did not occur and I was able to print the value ptr is pointing to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post you linked explains it more or less. One thing is doesn't touch on is undefined behavior - which is exactly what will happen in your version without `malloc`.

All sorts of things can go wrong if you try to use such a pointer - you haven't said *where* it *should* point to. It could point literally anywhere.

This line:

```
int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

**is** indeed an initialization. What's happening here is two things: (1) `malloc` is reserving space in memory so that you can subsequently use the pointer and (2) its returning the starting address of that memory.

The address gets assigned to `ptr` - which is itself a variable. And, like all variables, you *can't* use them uninitialized. If you do, that's invalid code and therefore, it results in undefined behavior.

**Let's drill down this point a little more:**

If you don't call `malloc`, your pointer is invalid and should not be used. To prove this, try compiling your code, say using good old `gcc`.

If you run:

```
gcc program.c  # no flags
```

it **will** compile -- but just because `gcc` gave you a binary, it doesn't mean it will do what you want. When you run it, it will (most of the time) fail miserably.

However, if you run:

```
gcc -Wall program.c  # enable warnings
```

it will **warn** you that `ptr` is being unused uninitialized. But, it will still produce a binary which you can run - resulting in the same thing as before.

Finally, if you run:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror program.c  # enable warnings and turn them into errors
```

it will again warn you of the same thing but this time, it won't produce a binary -- and this is what you really want in this situation. Here, `gcc` is *telling* you that something is really very wrong and that your code is simply not valid.

Now, back to the point about undefined behavior. Once you've compiled your invalid code (using either of the first two methods - BTW please never do this), running it will often give you a "segmentation fault" (seg fault). However, it doesn't have to and there are no guarantees as to what your program will do. **All variables, including pointers, need to be initialized.**

BTW, if you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770596/memory-allocation-in-stack-and-heap) post, it tells you *why* you need to call `malloc` here at all -- its because you're allocating memory dynamically, so it will be in the heap rather than on the stack.

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No

malloc does not initialize the variable. It just allocate the memory. You can put integer into the function, for example `malloc(8)`, it will just allocate 8 bytes for later use. If you look further into the malloc function, it actually returns `void*` datatype. It can be later typecasted into other datatype.

From your code `malloc(sizeof(int))`, actually `sizeof(int)` returns an integer for the size of the datatype/variable you put into it.

Comment: If I use `int *ptr = malloc(4);` I do not get segmentation default error from the second code block. The first code block that uses `int *ptr;` however returns segmentation fault when I try to print

Comment: @Shahin on your first code block, you do not allocate the memory needed. That's why you can't assign any value into it.

Comment: I think I understand it now. when I use `int *ptr;`. memory is allocated using `malloc()` for dynamic allocation or initialize an int variable for the pointer for static allocation (`int num; int *ptr = &num`). arrays also allocate memory: `int ptr[sizeof(int)]`

Answer (score 1):

**CASE I**:
Code:

```
int *ptr;
*ptr = 1000;
```

`*ptr` means you are dereferencing `ptr` pointer. Dereferencing an uninitialised pointer is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). An undefined behavior includes it may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended.

**CASE II**:
Code:

```
int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
*ptr = 1000;
```

`malloc` allocates memory block (of size in bytes) and returns the pointer to the beginning of newly allocated memory on success. The newly allocated block of memory is *not* initialised.

When doing this:

```
int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Assume `malloc` call is success and it returned pointer to beginning of newly allocated memory. This returned pointer will be assigned to `ptr` pointer. So, now the `ptr` pointer is *initialised* though the memory it is pointing to is *uninitialised*.
Since, the `ptr` pointer is pointing to a *valid* memory location, you can dereference it and access it.

In this statement

```
*ptr = 1000;
```

dereferencing `ptr` and assigning `1000` to that memory location. Now, the memory location which `ptr` pointer is pointing to contain value `1000`. Accessing this value perfectly fine.

---

**Additional:**

Follow the good programming practice - Always check the `malloc` return. You should do:

```
  int *ptr = malloc (sizeof (int));
  if (NULL == ptr) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // or whatever you want to do at malloc failure do it here
  }
```